# item changing with fade in/out (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

I want to create a menu in my web page, where each list item is represented by image. When  mouse point at some of these images, this image should fade out and be replaced by another image (I think fadeIn() would be useful).

HTML code:

```
<ul id="buttons">`    
    <li><a href="#" onmouseover="change(1)" onmouseout="ret(1)">  
        <img src="button01.png" id="button01_1" />
        <img src="button01_hover.png" id="button01_2"/>  
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onmouseover="change(2)" onmouseout="ret(2)">  
        <img src="button02.png" id="button02_1" />
        <img src="button02_hover.png" id="button02_2"/>  
     </a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery - I´m new in using jQuery, I tried this, but there are many mistakes. Pictures are not changing properly - "fadeIn" picture changes position (every list item is absolutely positioned), and first image is disapperaing and appearing constantly. Here´s the code:

```
function change(i)
{
    switch(i)
    {
        case 1:
            $("#button01_1").fadeOut(500); 
            $("#button01_2").fadeIn(500); 
            break;
        case 2:
            $("#button02_1").fadeOut(500);
            $("#button02_2").fadeIn(500);
    }
}
```

(ret(i) is similar..)

Thanks for help..

Comment: For future reference, just type all your code as is, then select all of it and click that button that looks like this: `{}`

Comment: (And, if you have a moment, take a look at the [Mark-down help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/) for further reference/guidance.)

Comment: Thanks, I´ll definitely read it

Comment: Depending on what browsers you support, you might want to use CSS instead: http://jsfiddle.net/yKQQB/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there but i can simplify:

```
<ul id="buttons">
    <li>
        <a href="#" id="link1">
            <img src="button01.png" id="button01_1" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" id="link2">
            <img src="button02.png" id="button02_1" />
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery code:

```
$('#link1').hover(function(){
    $('#button01_1').fadeOut(500).attr('src','button01_hover.png').fadeIn(500);
},function(){
    $('#button01_1').fadeOut(500).attr('src','button01.png').fadeIn(500);
});
```

With the selectors you could remove the id button01_1 and replace the jQuery selector to `$('img','#link')` to accommodate.
sorry if I've used too much of the jQuery library than javascript.

Function explained:

$('#link1').hover(function(){  --initial function on hover--  },function(){  --coming out of the hover--  });

EDIT :

jQuery library : `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Add the library to your html page

Comment: This is complete .js file? It´s not working.. List item are not reacting to mouse hover

Comment: Have you changed the html? I removed the second <img> and added the attribute 'id="link1"' to the anchor. Plus I removed the other javascript related attributes.

Comment: If I updated that jsfiddle, would you be able to see the changes that I make?

Comment: Yes, I changed that.. they are still not responding

Comment: Have you included the a jQuery source? I always use the google one as its g-ziped. <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
add to your html

Comment: I included the one offered to download on their official webpage. Another functions are working, so the problem is not in jQuery include. Have your tried this code on your PC and it´s working?

Comment: If other functions are running then there are no syntax errors. It must be a selector error, It works for me. What was that jsfiddle link again I'll try putting it on there for you.

Comment: What jsfiddle? Sorry I don´t know what do you mean

Comment: Nor do I, I've never used it, try this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/TN3e3/). First time of using it so let me know if it doesn't work and I'll host it for you.

Comment: I don´t know how to work on this site. With or without it, the problem is still not solved

Comment: well it sort of works lol [Check it here](http://www.benetosimonelli.com/test.html). I'm going to come up with something better.

Comment: This looks fine, but there is one problem - when your mouse remains on the image, it continues to fadeIn/Out ..

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the fact that fading out an image also triggers a mouseout, (since it has `display:none` once the fade out completes), which in turn triggers a fade in, and so on. Consider rethinking your logic.

Comment: @Ispuk You're right, I meant for that to be mouseover, but I realised that isn't the problem anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:**
use like this :

```
<ul id="buttons">    
    <li><a href="#" onmouseover="change($(this),1)" onmouseout="ret($(this),1)">  
        <img src="button01.png"/> 
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onmouseover="change($(this),2)" onmouseout="ret($(this),2)">  
        <img src="button02.png"/> 
     </a></li>
</ul>
```

jquery :

```
function change(elem ,i){
   $(elem).find('img').fadeOut('500',function(){
      $(this).attr('src','button0'+i+'_hover.png').fadeIn('2000');
   });
}
function ret(elem ,i){
   $(elem).find('img').fadeOut('500',function(){
       $(this).attr('src','button0'+i+'.png').fadeIn('2000');
   });
}
```

I hope that work ...

Comment: Something like this I wanted to create. But problem is, that hide() function causes first image disappear immediately, so in one moment there will be a gap (no image).. I need the fluent fade. I tried to use in your code fadeOut(500) instead of hide(), but it causes chaos in images´ behaviour.